# How is it that Santa rampages Earth every X-Mas, and MOM hasn't noticed yet?

Tags: futurama

We all know that Santa (a corrupt robot based on Neptune) comes to Earth with many, many weapons and terrorizes Earth every X-Mas. Since Earth also contains MOM's friendly robot company, he must terrorize the company's HQ too somewhere in there.

MOM - Having her thousand KILLBOTS - never seems to get annoyed (and by annoyed I mean all out enraged) by Santa. How is this? Shouldn't there have been some all out war between MOM and Santa?

Answer (score 2):

While Santa's programing has led him to believe all people are bad, Mom of Mom's Friendly Robots is, as the Mother's Day episode showed us, still his mother.  While he wreaks havoc on X-Mas, he leaves his mother alone.  Mom being the way she is doesn't care seeing as it doesn't affect her.

Comment: Not all people, Zoidberg got a pogo stick.

Answer (score 1):

Two possible reasons:

1. Mom built Santa and has programmed him not to attack her HQ.
2. There is nothing mentioned in the programme that shows that Mom even knows of Santa's existence. How can she get annoyed if she doesn't know he's there?

Comment: The second point I have hard time believing mostly becouse everyone knows about Santa and everyone stays inside so I just guess that Mom does the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think that Mom secretly lets Santa run amok on Christmas because it allows one of her creations to terrorize the world while no one notices that she lets it happen because they are all too afraid to say something to her. On the other side, by allowing Santa to terrorize the world she keeps a control on peoples dependence on robots because when Santa destroys buildings and cars and injures people, Mom's company is allowed to produce more robots to fix the damage that Santa has caused, allowing Mom's company to generate an enormous profit while secretly terrorizing the world, as stated before. Plus I think Santa is controlled by Mom, so every Christmas she sends a programmed message ordering Santa not to attack her company.

Answer (score 0):

MOM made Santa Bot, so she knows he's there. But I think the answer is that she simply programmed him, like all other robots of hers, to be controlled via remote, which she most likely used after santa went crazy to save herself. If she can make robots rise up against humanity, I think that she can tell a killer robot not to kill her with a push of a different button.

Answer (score 0):

Mom is somewhat of a tyrannical monopolizer on the robot manufacturing trade. Santa is just her way of keeping people in check with the status quo of living with robots and dealing with whatever they must. Santa was made as a "renegade" such as the Sheriff of Nottingham.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that The Friendly Robot company that built Santa was just Mom's Friendly Robot Company when Mom was much younger, so she had Santa programmed to always judge her as nice. Therefore he never bothers her and is also carrying out the exact purpose she wanted him to do.

Answer (score 0):

**Santa was made by a team of scientists and/ or engineers**, not from Mom's Friendly Robot company.  By that, Santa isn't made from Mom's corporation.  Just a bunch of scientists who got killed when Santa deemed them Naughty due to the fact that the group made a killing machine.